# CSS font-size wrecking placement

Tags: html, css, position, alignment, font-size

I have two elements that are fairly unrelated, the `.menu`, and the `.content_selection_button`. The only thing that ties them together is that they are both inside `<li>` elements in the same `<ul>`, other than that they share nothing. Yet, for some reason when I change the font-size of a `.content_selection_button` it affects the vertical placement of the menu. I had a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539930/css-font-size-knocks-out-html-aligntment). Why is font-size ruining my placement, and how can I stop it?

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/easilyBaffled/2fL5E/)**

**Font Size 10**

[image: Font Size 10]

**Font Size 25**

[image: Font Size 25]

**Menu CSS**

```
.menu {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:lightblue;
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

**Content Selection Button CSS**

```
.content_selection_button{
    font-size: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="t_inject_container">
    <li class="t_inject_row">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li id="LI_4">
                <button class="add_button t_intect_button">
                    +
                </button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button class="minimize_button t_intect_button">
                    m
                </button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul class="content_selection_container">
            <li>
                <form name="search_form" class="search_form">
                    <input type="text" name="search_input" class="search_bar" />
                    <input type="submit" value="" class="search_button" name="search_button" />
                </form>
            </li>
            <li id="LI_14">
                <button class="content_selection_button">
                    My Timeline
                </button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button class="content_selection_button">
                    relevent
                </button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button class="content_selection_button">
                    mentions
                </button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you provide a js fiddle with more styling, this is difficult to debug like that? Also inline-block is by default set to vertical-align: middle

Comment: @JohanVandenRym Not true, the initial value of `vertical-align` is `baseline`

Comment: @JohanVandenRym I added the fiddle

Comment: @Oriol Yep, you are right - it is baseline.

Comment: @JohanVandenRym but what does the baseline have to do with the menu. I had a similar problem where search button was out of alignment with the search bar because it was too big, but here they are separate elements.

Comment: Thought since you have inline-block elements that you could fix the vertical alignment (setting it to bottom) but than IMHO using one single UL to create this kind of UI it is overcomplicated.

Comment: @JohanVandenRym ok so it set * {vertical-align :  text-bottom;} worked like a charm. I'll have to play a bit cause *{} is bad but it works! Thanks. Write up and answer and I'll give you the vote. As for the <ul> it seemed like a good system based on how the project will be growing

Comment: From a semantic point of view ULs are suited for listings, navigation but not to add UI elements (except tabs than IMHO).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hinted that playing with bottom vertical alignment of the inline-block elements could fix the alignment issues. *This could be avoided by simplyfing the UI by reworking the mark-up and CSS.*

```
[ELEMENT] {
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've main parent element's with height 150px with LI inside 25% height. so that comes around 37.5px. The height wont increase due to the increase in font size, but it will affect the calculated line height, the line-height will increase pushing the text below a central axis of the button.

Comment: And this causes everything else to move? Why wouldn't the text just move inside the element and leave everything else alone?